# Why doesn't this regex work in Python 3?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to match `(.)\1+` in `google`. This works just fine on http://regexr.com/, but when I try this code in Python, r.match(s) returns None.

```
import re

s = 'google'

r = re.compile(r'(.)\1+')

print(r.match(s))
```

Comment: Use `print(r.search(s))` instead

Comment: [search vs match](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match) in docs